# For what $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}$ is $A\in\mathbb{Z}^{4\times 4}$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having problems understanding the solution to the problem mentioned in the title, which is finding $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}$ for which $A\in\mathbb{Z}^{4\times4}$ is invertible:

$$A_\alpha=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 0 & 3 \\
    0 & -3 & 5 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & -2 & 2 \\
   -1 & 0 & 0 & \alpha
    \end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{Z}^{4\times 4}$$

With determinant $\det(A_\alpha)=\alpha+27$
In general a square matrix is invertible, if its determinant is not equal to $0$, so I would say that it is invertible for all $\alpha\neq-27$, however according to the exercise book, the matrix is not invertible for $\alpha=0$. Note that the question says "invertible over $\mathbb{Z}$", yet I do not understand how this changes the definition of invertibility, or how that means that $A_\alpha$ is not invertible for $\alpha=0$. Thanks

Comment: Take the easier example of a $1\times 1$-matrix $A=(2)$. Although the determinant is nonzero, it is not invertible over $\Bbb Z$, since $\frac{1}{2}\not\in \Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inverse needs to have integer coefficients, too, if we consider the matrix over $\Bbb Z$. So $A\in GL_n(\Bbb Z)$ implies that $\det(A)$ is a unit in $\Bbb Z$, i.e., is $\pm 1$.

And for $\alpha=0$, the matrix $A$ does not satisfy $\det(A)=\pm 1$, so that
$A\not\in GL_4(\Bbb Z)$ for $\alpha=0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, how does this compare to for example $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @phhhlpfk We generally only speak of matrices over rings - that is, sets with well-behaved addition, subtraction, and multiplication. The general result is that a square matrix $A$ with coefficients in a ring $R$ has an inverse iff its determinant is a "unit" in $R$; that is, if there is some $x \in R$ such that $x \cdot det(A) = 1$ in $R$. In the special case that $R$ is a field (that is, division by nonzero numbers is well-defined), the condition that $det(A)$ is a unit is equivalent to the condition that $det(A) \neq 0$.